# Exception not being created or displayed

Tags: java, loops, exception, while-loop

I'm doing an assignment where I have to create a schedule and handle certain exceptions for bad input.  I have it working mostly but for my generic exception throw it doesn't seem to be creating the object that I want.  I used an overloaded constructor to create it and when I call the message it doesn't display my input.  My code is as follows:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Exception;

public class Scheduler{
public static void main() throws Exception{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name;
    int time;

    // Program introduction

    System.out.println("Welcome to scheduling scheduler 2.0");
    System.out.println("You can schedule an appointment at 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6 pm");

    // Creating the Array

    String[] schedule = new String[6];

    // While loop set to 

    while(filled(schedule) == false){
        System.out.print("What is your name? ");
        name = input.next();
        boolean innerExecute = true;

        // Do While loop used in order to loop until a valid time is set instead of asking for
        // name again

        do{
            try{
                System.out.print("When do you want to schedule your appointment? ");
                time = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println();
                if(time > 6 || time < 1){
                    throw new InvalidTimeException("Sorry that is not a valid time");
                }

                else if(schedule[time - 1] == null){
                    schedule[time - 1] = name;
                    innerExecute = false;
                }

                else if(schedule[time - 1] != null){
                    throw new TimeInUseException("That time is not available.");
                }

                else{
                    throw new Exception("Bad time format, should be an integer.");
                }

            }

            catch(TimeInUseException e){
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                System.out.println();
            }
            catch(InvalidTimeException e){
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                System.out.println();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                System.out.println();
                String voided = input.next();
            }

        }while(innerExecute == true);
    }

    System.out.println("The schedule is as follows: ");
    System.out.println();
    for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
        System.out.print("At " + (i+1) + " PM is " + schedule[i]);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

My output is:

```
Welcome to scheduling scheduler 2.0
You can schedule an appointment at 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6 pm
What is your name? don
When do you want to schedule your appointment? 
,
null

When do you want to schedule your appointment?
```

All other exceptions are displayed correctly but this one prints null instead.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, when `nextInt()` finds something other than an `int` to return, it throws an `InputMismatchException` without a message. Therefore `getMessage()` returns `null`. Try using `Exception#printStackTrace()` to view the stack trace instead.

Answer (score 0):

When you input `,` you'll get an InputMismatchException, you need process user's input firstly, cause user may input anything.

```
try {
    time = input.nextInt();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    System.out.println("Your input should be a number!");
    continue;
}
```

[image]